# Can get_dummies lead to a feature_names mismatch error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding

I built an XGBoost model predicting whether a sample will attend college or not, so a categorical model. I used GridSearchCV to find the best params and have tested the model's accuracy. I am now trying to predict on "unknown" data, but create a DataFrame with one row using the same column names and preprocessing including get_dummies, but I'm getting a "feature_names mismatch" error. When utilizing get_dummies, would the ordering differ every time it's used?

Initial DataFrame:

```
type_school                     Academic
school_accreditation                   A
gender                              Male
interest                 Less Interested
residence                          Urban
parent_age                            56
parent_salary                    6950000
house_area                          83.0
average_grades                     84.09
parent_was_in_college              False
in_college                          True
```

new DataFrame:

```
new_data = [['Academic', 'A', 'Male', 'Less Interested', 'Urban', 56, 
6950000, 83.0, 84.09, 
False]]

new = pd.DataFrame(data=new_data, columns = ['type_school', 'school_accreditation', 'gender', 
'interest', 'residence', 'parent_age', 'parent_salary', 'house_area', 'average_grades', 
'parent_was_in_college'])
```

code to get_dummies used for the inital Dataframe and the new one:

```
X_Encoded = pd.get_dummies(X,X.select_dtypes('object').columns, drop_first=True)
X_new = pd.get_dummies(new,new.select_dtypes('object').columns, drop_first=True)
```

Is this a situation in which get_dummies doesn't produce the same order as previously? If so, how can I fix this?

Comment: `pd.get_dummies` can result in missing/additional columns if the same categories are not present in both of your datasets. Use sklearn's [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) instead

Comment: Tried OneHotEncoder and got the following : "TypeError: Singleton array array(OneHotEncoder(), dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection."

    enc_X = OneHotEncoder()
    enc_X.fit(X)

Answer (score 0):

`pd.get_dummies` is sensitive not to the order of columns, but to the range of values observed in the data. Specifically, if new data doesn't have specific value, say `old_value`, then `pd.get_dummies(new_data)` will not create a column for `old_value`.

For more robust processing, you want to use scikit-learn's `OneHotEncoder`, which can be trained to know the possible values and will always create corresponding columns, even if a value is not observed in the new data.